# C# equivalent of Python repr()

Tags: c#, python

Is there a C# method like Python's repr() to get the true representation of the object? Suppose we have:

```
string identifier = "22\n44";
Console.WriteLine(identifier);
```

This would return

```
22
44
```

Is there a way to get

```
"22\n44"
```

In Python this is easy. We can just do `repr("22\n44")`.

I thought of this question because I was trying to convert `"2244"` to `'2244'` using

```
var identifier = "2244";
identifier = identifier.Replace("\"", "'");
Console.WriteLine(identifier);
```

The output is just `2244`, because double quotes are for our purpose. But in my case, I  did this to get what I wanted:

```
identifier = string.Format("'{0}'", identifier);
```

because initially the database was receiving the query as `IN ("2244")` instead of `IN ('2244')` and was throwing Invalid Number error.

Comment: Don't do DB input like that, you're leaving the door open for [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: And using `repr()` to 'escape' values for database insertion is just as wrong in Python as it is in C#.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: I didn't downvote, but this does read like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps the OP should ask about the `Invalid Number` error instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you can do `"22\n44".repr()` if you provide extension method.

Comment: @walkhard: are we still talking about Python here?

Comment: @TimS. I am aware of SQL Injection. However, in this case the value sent to database is not a user input, but a value parsed from the UI itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think what he's looking for is how to create a raw string in C#. My knowledge of C# is abysmal, so I might be wrong. Also, he _did_ show expected output.

Comment: @Animesh Regardless, if it's logically a number then it should be typed as a number, not a string, and inserted into the query as a number, not as a string.  This will, among other things, assure that your numbers are always numbers and you *cannot possibly ever* have improperly formatted numbers in your query.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I though we're talking about `C# method like Python's repr()`

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Sure, but that's still an XY problem. The *actual* problem that the OP is solving is how to generate a `IN (...)` SQL query from variable input.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, there's noting about SQL here.

Comment: @walkhard: The OP claimed, before editing, that *in Python*, you'd simply use `str.repr()`, while no such method exists.

Comment: @walkhard Keep in mind that the escape sequences for your database are entirely different than the escape sequences for strings in C#.  Translating a query into what the escaped version would be in C# doesn't mean it'll be appropriate input for a database, so your `repr` method wouldn't actually work in this case, even if one existed.

Comment: @Servy well I got lost, on one way OP wants to get `"22\n44"` on other he wants to use it in `IN` as `2244` (without `\n`), so I've provided an answer for the question. You're right that escape sequences in database can be different than those in C#, yet it doesn't mean that it's an inappropriate input for a database.

Comment: @walkhard There is some overlap, so it will sometimes work, and then it will sometimes fail.  That doesn't make it an acceptable solution to the problem, it's just fixing the current example while still leaving a ticking time bomb around.

Comment: @Servy Ahh those are the best bugs, aren't they? Though if we're talking about the core problem here, then it seems that `2244` is a integer value, so there is no reason to have fun with escape sequences here. Anyways this question generated a lot of comments and an upvoted wrong answer. Perhaps I should consider removing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string identifier = "22\n44";
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", identifier.Replace("\n", @"\n"));
```